# swift: timer (every second) + gestureRecognizer crashs the GUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, timer, crash, uigesturerecognizer

I have a simple gestureRecognizer. When the gesture is "UP" then the menu slides up. "DOWN": The menu slides down. This works.

I have a timer too. It simply counts a number++ every second. This works, too. But together the timer is crashing my GUI. 
The animation starts correctly, but when the timer calls my counter-method it's jumping back to the origin GUI.

What kind of problem is that? I found nothing at google, but I think  I searched the wrong words. (English isn't my mothertongue and in german there isn't so much literature...)

Here are fragments of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var swipe: UILabel!
var number: Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var topSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    var downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

    topSwipe.direction = .Up
    downSwipe.direction = .Down

    view.addGestureRecognizer(topSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "counter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func counter() {
    number++
    swipe.text = "\(number)"
}

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.direction == .Up) {
        print("TOP")

            var menuPosition = CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.origin.x, self.menuView.frame.origin.y - 100.0)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.65, animations: {
                self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(menuPosition.x,menuPosition.y,self.menuView.frame.size.width,self.menuView.frame.size.height)
                })


    }

    if (sender.direction == .Down) {
            menuChoose = true
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.65, animations: {

            var menuPosition = CGPointMake(self.menuView.frame.origin.x, self.menuView.frame.origin.y + 100.0)
        self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(menuPosition.x,menuPosition.y,self.menuView.frame.size.width,self.menuView.frame.size.height)
            })
    }

  }   
}
```

I tried to lock the timer. So when the gesture begins, then just count the number without swipe.text = "(number)"
The animation goes to end, but after an "unlock" the GUI jumped back to the origin.

Thank u for some codesnippets or keywords that I can search :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that whenever a `UILabel`'s `text` property is set, it redraws the view, resulting in resetting `menuView`'s position (perhaps someone can elaborate on the "why" in a comment). If you use auto layout constraints to manipulate the position of `menuView`, it works. You can do this by setting `spaceConstraint.constant += 100` or `spaceConstraint.constant -= 100` and then calling

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.65, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: A strange thing but ur solution works and I learned more abouts gui's. Thank u a lot mate!!! If somebody knows about the why, then tell us please :)